# owin map extension return 404

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I tried to implement a middleware just for my web API actions, so i found `Map` that is a extension method of `IAppBuilder` inerface. i checked katana source code [[1](https://github.com/yreynhout/katana-clone/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin/Mapping/MapExtensions.cs)], this method return an `IAppBuilder` same as `Use` method.

but in owin/WebAPI i don't know why controllers dose not resolve after mapping?

its clear after invoking next middleware, owin should run next middleware, but after mapping it seems there is no next middleware, where is my mistake?

StartUp:

```
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);


            app = app.Map("/api", application => {
                ConfigurationAPI(application);
            });


            app.Use<ExceptionMiddleware>();
            //app.UseWebApi(config);
        }


        public void ConfigurationAPI(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            FilterConfig.RegisterHttpFilters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);

            SimpleInjectorBootstrapper.Initialize();
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(SharedLayer.Core.CoreObject.container));
            config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(SharedLayer.Core.CoreObject.container);

            app = app.Use<ExceptionMiddleware>();
            app = app.Use<AuthenticateMiddleware>();
            app.UseWebApi(config);

        }
```

but when I add following run block, all requests  return "test"!!

```
        app.Run(async context =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("test");
        });
        app.UseWebApi(config);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do your route definitions include the `/api` segment? Map removes that from the path for it's branch of the pipeline (ConfigurationAPI).